# VB.NET printing images using a lot of memory

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing

I'm working with PDFs in VB.NET using a DLL I found on code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37458/PDF-Viewer-Control-Without-Acrobat-Reader-Installe

My app allows you to select multiple files in a grid and print them. The files are stored in password-protected zip files, so the first step I do is extract each selected file to a memory stream that I pass to a new PDF wrapper object. Each object gets added to a queue. Then, each object in the queue is printed, page by page, as a system.drawing.image. The whole thing runs on a background worker.

Now, extracting the PDFs to the queue uses hardly any memory. But in the PrintPage event handler, when I extract the images and send them to the printer, something must be going wrong. My memory usage explodes. Each image, of course, is large because it's rendered at 300 dpi, but the memory used by each page isn't being returned to the OS and neither is it being garbage collected.

In the end, if I select enough files, I run out of memory. Why?

Comment: Including some relevant portions of your code in the question may help  you to get an answer to your question.

Comment: Forgetting to call the Image.Dispose() method is a standard mistake.

Comment: When you are dealing with graphics or bitmaps its best to dispose the instance after each pass so that it doesn't build up useless memory. Simply use the Dispose method

Comment: I am calling dispose, but the memory isn't released, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out.

First, as far as the images go, the CLR apparently doesn't know how much memory is allocated for a `Drawing.Image` so when you dispose it, you have to tell it:

```
'It's 4 bytes per pixel with RGBA
'Use Drawing.Image.PixelFormat to get
'the number of bytes if you don't know
Dim countBytes as long = 4 * img.Width * img.Height

'Let the CLR know of the memory we want to free
if countBytes > 0 then GC.AddMemoryPressure(countBytes)

'Get rid of the image
img.Dispose()
img = Nothing

'Free up the unused memory
GC.Collect()

'Tell the CLR we took care of it
GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(countBytes)
```

Now, the PDF library from the CodeProject sample was quite a bit more difficult.

First of all, make sure you call the `Dispose` method on the `PDFWrapper` object in either the `FormClosed` event of the form that holds the wrapper, or in the `Finalize` method of the class that holds it.

But, the `PDFWrapper` actually seems to cache the images you retrieve from it. So as you page through a PDF, memory usage will grow until the images for entire PDF are cached. This is an even bigger problem if you use those images to print the PDF at 300DPI (I get out of memory errors toward the end of a 60+ page PDF at 1.5GB of memory used).

There is no 'Clear Cache' method for this object as far as I can tell. But the hack I used to get it working was to grab an image at 1DPI after I get the image I need, then perform garbage collection as above. This indirectly frees up the memory that was cached. However, like before, we must tell the CLR how many bytes we used. It's the same calculation as above.

BUT there is one more problem. The `PDFWrapper` object is actually grabbing the images on another thread, it seems. So, by requesting another 1DPI image after we request the 300DPI image, it gets confused and randomly spits out 1DPI images when it should be giving us 300DPI images to print. So, the workaround for this:

```
Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
img = AFPDFLibUtil.GetImageFromPDF(pdfWrapper, currentPage, DPI)

'Wait for PDFWrapper to finish rendering
Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
sw.Start()
While _pdfWrapper.IsBusy
    If sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < TimeoutMS Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
    Else
        Throw New Exception("This page took too long to render.")
    End If
End While
sw.Stop()
sw.Reset()
```

And there you go. Perhaps that's why in the CodeProject sample, he uses a different DLL to do the printing. However, the `PDFWrapper` object supports reading from a `IO.MemoryStream`, I don't think any of the other includes in that project do.

Happy coding to anyone who reads this!